# how to import and preserve relationships of CSV Neo4j Graph database

Tags: neo4j, csv-import

I am trying to import a CSV into Neo4j in order to create a graph database of the data. This is data from an archaeological dig, where the specific artifacts found are given a unique "FS Number". When the dig is conducted, a site is divided into a grid, with each square being called a feature. Features can be subdivided into sub-features, in the case of this dig there are 4 feature levels, Feature 4 being the biggest division and Feature 1 being the smallest.

Thus, the way this data already is, you have many features within features, though the relationship between a sub feature and a primary feature should be one to many, that is a sub feature can only be in one primary feature, but a primary feature can have multiple sub features. In importing my data however, the database links several sub-features to multiple primary features.

I have played around with the importation and relationship graph that is provided by the Neo4j workspace, but this distinction about the relationship cannot be preserved it seems. I have attached the diagram that I created for the importation. Anyway I can improve this to avoid this issue?
Edit 6/26/23: I should have provided a quick overview fo the CSV sorry, I have attached a photo of how it generally works. Each row is an artifact with an FS number as well as certain feature associations. Some artifacts may only have Feature 4 association, others may have a Feature 4 and Feature 3, or Feature 4, Feature 3 and Feature 2 associations. Each artifact has to have at least a Feature 4 association since that is the uppermost division of the site. There are more columns than shown in the photo, but all that matters for this graph database is the feature associations and the FS number for the artifact to construct these relations.

[image: Importation Graph created in Neo4j workspace]

[Original CSV demosntrating column format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkMBJ.png)

Comment: Please show enough of your CSV file to give an idea of its structure.

Answer (score 0):

I took a picture of my Data Importer screen for you to check against yours. The biggest step that might be easy to miss is to use the `Map from File` button on the right panel to map the fields for each node because the labels in the model do not exactly match what's in the CSV (FS_Artifact vs FS#, Feature2 vs Feature 2). It also confused me on the visualization when I queried the data in Neo4j Browser that the node label was showing a different property than the FS#, so you can click on the label and choose FS# to solve that problem. I hope this helps[image: Data Importer view]

Comment: Thanks but I have used "Map from file" button when creating this import schema. I am getting the nodes to link to the proper information so far as I can tell. My problem is that sub features are getting linked to muliple primary features. For example, a particular Feature 4 has a specific Feature 3 with a number that other Feature 3 may have in different Feature 4 sections. In the graph database, Feature 3 gets linked to multiple Feature 4 sections when the import happens and then merges the artifact information that is contained in that Feature.

Comment: Ah, so you're not wanting to merge unique values for features then. Each row should be a separate chain, correct? For example, in the data below, even though the Feature3 values are the same (26), you want separate nodes created and connected to FS# 3849 and FS# 3850.
```
3849,Ceramic,,214,26,12,1178,853,5,5.87,5.98
3850,Ceramic,,215,26,12,1177,852,5,5.97,6.08
```

Comment: Yes, each row should be a unique chain, though their higher features should be instersecting, like if an artifact is in the same Feature 4 as another.

Comment: Ok. Currently, there is no way to turn off MERGE default in Data Importer, which ensures unique values and doesn't allow creation of duplicate nodes. That may be the problem. Another way around this is to construct the structure you want using Cypher. Happy to help, if you want to go that route.

Comment: Ok, how would I construct this structure in Cypher? I am still learning it and part of hte reason I did it this route was because it was easier to conceptualize, but if you could point me in the right direction with the Cypher code that would be nice

Comment: Are you still able to help me formualte a cypher code line that can help me complete this import?

Comment: Apologize for the delay! I just re-read your initial issue, and I'm wondering if I misunderstood the hierarchy of data objects. Should it be FS# -> Feature4 -> Feature3 -> Feature2? If so, you can adjust the data model in importer to match that. If not, example Cypher for the other model would be something like the following:
```LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from <file> as row
MERGE (f:FS_Artifact {FS#: row.FS#})
MERGE (f2:`Feature 2` {`Feature 2`: row.`Feature 2`})
MERGE (f)-[rel:IS_IN]->(f2)```